# What is the meaning of the phrase "swing the bat" or "swing the bat often"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

From an article titled [*5 Things Super Lucky People Do*](http://www.inc.com/kevin-daum/5-things-super-lucky-people-do.html):

> The [successful] competitors are simply **swinging the bat more often**.

What is the meaning of the phrase *swing the bat more often*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article makes a point that those successful competitors (salespeople) are not lucky. They simply **make more attempts** (in other words, they make more calls). The article compares the sales with a popular sport, baseball.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseball),

> Baseball is a bat-and-ball game played between two teams of nine players each who take turns batting and fielding.
>
> The offense attempts to score runs by hitting a ball thrown by the pitcher with a bat and moving counter-clockwise around a series of four bases: first, second, third, and home plate. [...]

When a play starts, the batter will swing the bat the best they can, trying to hit the ball thrown by the pitcher. All things being equal, a batter who swings more often will hit the ball more often.

Comment: +1 Exactly. Batting is a popular metaphor with salespeople because even the greatest batters fail more often than they succeed: getting a hit once in every three attempts (BA = .333) puts you among the elite. No one has hit .400 for a full season since 1941; no one has ever hit .440.

Comment: @StoneyB Nice stats!